# How to make Promise.all wait till then statements in individual promises have completed?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of objects and for each object, I need to run an asynchronous function and add a value to that object depending on what the async function returns.

My problem is my Promise.all is returning when all my promises have been fulfilled but before the conditional inside each promise's `then` statement has a chance to update its object:

```
  function addInlineImageToContentElements(elements) {
    const newElements = elements;
    const promiseArray = [];

    if (newElements) {
      newElements.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (el.type === 'story' && !el.promo_items) {
          getFirstInlineImage(el._id).then((firstInlineImage) => {
            if (firstInlineImage) {
              newElements[i].firstInlineImage = firstInlineImage;
            }
          });
          promiseArray.push(getFirstInlineImage);
        }
      });
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => newElements);
  }
```

As a result, newElements is getting returned before it gets a chance to be updated.

Comment: either wrap it in another `Promise` or try `async await`

Comment: does that help?

Comment: You don't seem to push the promise into the array but the function `getFirstInlineImage` which creates a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You don't push the promise into the array but the function `getFirstInlineImage` which creates a promise.

Try to change the code within your second if statement to this:

```
const promise = getFirstInlineImage(el._id).then((firstInlineImage) => {
    if (firstInlineImage) {
        newElements[i].firstInlineImage = firstInlineImage;
    }
});
promiseArray.push(promise);
```